# Static analysis and the "create rule"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation, clang-static-analyzer, llvm-clang

I want to add a category on NSBezierPath to return a CGPathRef for the path. Since this is a core foundation object, I cannot autorelease it, and the caller of the method is responsible for releasing it. By placing either "Copy" or "Create" as part of the method name, I think I am following the convention set by Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

However, the static analyzer won't accept it unless I go even further, and—not only include create/copy as part of the name, but—actually start the method name with "copy" (or mutableCopy, etc).

However, doing so is in violation of best practice for naming category methods, as they should be prefixed to avoid naming collision.

What is the best way of achieving all of the following:

1. Adding a method on a category on a Cocoa class
2. … that returns a Core Foundation object
3. … that will give no warnings in the analyzer
4. … and are named according to best practices?

Comment: I believe you **can** autorelease it, since CFTypeRef is toll-free bridged with NSObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this you mean:

```
//
//  NSBezierPath+MCAdditions.h
//
//  Created by Sean Patrick O'Brien on 4/1/08.
//  Copyright 2008 MolokoCacao. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AnalyzerMacros.h"

@interface NSBezierPath (MCAdditions)

+ (NSBezierPath *)bezierPathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)pathRef;
- (CGPathRef)cgPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;

- (NSBezierPath *)pathWithStrokeWidth:(CGFloat)strokeWidth;

- (void)fillWithInnerShadow:(NSShadow *)shadow;
- (void)drawBlurWithColor:(NSColor *)color radius:(CGFloat)radius;

- (void)strokeInside;
- (void)strokeInsideWithinRect:(NSRect)clipRect;

@end
```

It's not my code; I added the `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` to help the static analyzer out.

The full reference to clang source annotations is available [here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html).

Comment: Thanks, that did it! A question: If a metod that has been attributed with CF_RETURNS_RETAINED are exposed in a public API of a framework, and that framework is used in a project that's using ARC; Will ARC use the CF_RETURNS_RETAINED attribute to figure out that object is retained, regardless if the method is named "create", "copy", etc?

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen Sorry, I don't know the answer to that... I don't use ARC.

Answer (score 1):

For clarification: the root class of CoreFoundation objects, CFTypeRef, is toll-free bridged with NSObject. That means you can autorelease CoreFoundation objects (after doing an appropriate cast).

Comment: Question: If the project in question is using ARC, is there anyway to return a CFTypeRef without it having retain count +1?